# Filter datetime columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2014

I have a datetime column that has a 5 min interval between the next data, however I want to see if that column contains any time interval less than 5 mins, particularly 5 secs.

So for example:

- one date would read `2018-05-04 19:21:46.000`
- the next row would read `2018-05-04 19:26:46.000`
- and `2018-05-04 19:31:46.000`.

However, we sometimes get rows that read:

- `2018-05-04 19:36:46.000`
- then `2018-05-04 19:36:51.000`
- then `2018-05-04 19:36:56.000`

What SQL script would be best to filter the column to distinguish the erroneous data (the 5 secs interval) from the correct data (5 min interval) especially in a table with thousands of rows?

Hi @Andrea, thanks for that. I have a couple of questions. What does the 'q' stand for? and when i rewrite the query as

```
SELECT  ProductID, MyTimestamp, DATEDIFF(second, xMyTimestamp, MyTimestamp) as DIFFERENCE_IN_SECONDS
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                Lag(MyTimestamp) OVER (ORDER BY MyTimestamp, ProductID) as xMyTimestamp
        FROM    TableName
        ) q
WHERE   xMyTimestamp IS NOT NULL and ProductID= 31928
```

I get this result which doesn't compute the time accurately.

```
+-----------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| ProductID |       MyTimestamp       | DIFFERENCE_IN_SECONDS |
+-----------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
|     31928 | 2017-03-21 13:36:30.000 |                     0 |
|     31928 | 2017-03-21 13:46:30.000 |                     0 |
|     31928 | 2017-03-21 13:56:32.000 |                     0 |
|     31928 | 2017-03-21 14:01:32.000 |                     0 |
|     31928 | 2017-03-21 14:11:32.000 |                     0 |
|     31928 | 2017-03-21 14:16:32.000 |                     0 |
|     31928 | 2017-03-21 14:26:32.000 |                     0 |
|     31928 | 2017-03-21 14:36:32.000 |                     0 |
+-----------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Any reason why

Comment: Supposed that the next record will be "correct", what will be? 19:41:46 or 19:41:56?

Comment: @WolfgangK, if i understand your question correctly, the correct record in the difference in seconds field, should not read zero but calculate the time difference between the succeeding value in Mytimestamp and the preceeding Value in the MyTimestamp field. So it shoul have read, 600, 602, 300, 600, 300 etc. but instead it reads 0.

Comment: No, you did not understand my question, and since the sample data has left the question, you can't.
My question is: Will the next "correct" value be 5 minutes after the last "correct" value or 5 minutes after the last record no matter if it was correct or not?

For the "Difference 0": Partition By ProductID and remove it from Order By. The most likely cause of that problem is multiple products with the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LAG`:

```
declare @tmp table(MyTimestamp datetime)

insert into @tmp values
('2018-05-04 19:21:46.000')
,('2018-05-04 19:26:46.000')
,('2018-05-04 19:31:46.000')
,('2018-05-04 19:36:46.000')
,('2018-05-04 19:36:51.000')
,('2018-05-04 19:36:56.000')


SELECT  DATEDIFF(second, xMyTimestamp, MyTimestamp) as DIFFERENCE_IN_SECONDS
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                LAG(MyTimestamp) OVER (ORDER BY MyTimestamp) xMyTimestamp
        FROM    @tmp
        ) q
WHERE   xMyTimestamp IS NOT NULL
```

results:

[image]

So you should use it like this:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(second, xMyTimestamp, MyTimestamp) as DIFFERENCE_IN_SECONDS
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                LAG(MyTimestamp) OVER (ORDER BY MyTimestamp) xMyTimestamp
        FROM    [YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE]
        ) q
WHERE   xMyTimestamp IS NOT NULL
```

---

*Edit*

Here is another sample based on new data posted by OP:

```
declare @tmp table(ProductID int, MyTimestamp datetime)

insert into @tmp values
 (31928, '2017-03-21 13:36:30.000')
,(31928, '2017-03-21 13:46:30.000')
,(31928, '2017-03-21 13:56:32.000')
,(31928, '2017-03-21 14:01:32.000')
,(31928, '2017-03-21 14:11:32.000')
,(31928, '2017-03-21 14:16:32.000')
,(31928, '2017-03-21 14:26:32.000')
,(31928, '2017-03-21 14:36:32.000')

SELECT ProductID
    ,MyTimestamp
    ,DATEDIFF(second, xMyTimestamp, MyTimestamp) AS DIFFERENCE_IN_SECONDS
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,Lag(MyTimestamp) OVER (
            ORDER BY MyTimestamp
                ,ProductID
            ) AS xMyTimestamp
    FROM @tmp
    ) q
WHERE xMyTimestamp IS NOT NULL
    AND ProductID = 31928
```

Output:

[image]

[Here](http://rextester.com/MKY41957) you can check that the results are calculated correctly.

Comment: Thanks Andrea, this looks great but with a table of over thousands of rows, i don't suppose i would have to insert that many values. to then select the difference.

Comment: @DBANewbie This is only a sample to show you that the solution works. You now have to ignore the `insert` section of the script and to replace `@tmp` with your actual table name. See updated answer.

Comment: Hi @Andrea, thanks for the response. Please see original post for more questions

Comment: @DBANewbie `q` is just an alias needed to use the subquery. I tested the code with the values you provided: it works correctly. Plese see updated answer and the Rextester link.

Comment: Thanks @Andrea. I see that, it's the exact same query except that you inserted those values into the table variable. I'm trying to retrieve those results from a large table yet i don't see how i am not getting the right calculations in the last column.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on 2014, you can use `LEAD` to compare the value of one row, to the value of the next.

```
declare @table table(id int identity(1,1), interval datetime)
insert into @table
values
('2018-05-04 19:21:46.000'),
('2018-05-04 19:26:46.000'),
('2018-05-04 19:31:46.000'),

('2018-05-04 19:36:46.000'),
('2018-05-04 19:36:51.000'),
('2018-05-04 19:36:56.000')

select
    id
    ,interval
    ,issue_with_row = case 
                            when 
                                isnull(datediff(minute,interval,lead(interval) over (order by id, interval)),0) < 5 
                            then 1 
                            else 0 
                        end
from @table
order by id
```

Or if you wanted to only see those,

```
;with cte as(
select
    id
    ,interval
    ,issue_with_row = case 
                            when 
                                isnull(datediff(minute,interval,lead(interval) over (order by id, interval)),0) < 5 
                            then 1 
                            else 0 
                        end
from @table)

select *
from cte 
where issue_with_row = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @scsimon, but does your second query adjust for a table with unlimited rows rather than the example i provided.

Comment: Yes it does @DBANewbie just replace it with your table